# Is it theoretically possible to split a photon into two that are coherent with the original?

Tags: photons, coherence

Purely theoretically speaking, is there a reason a photon cannot be turned into two lower energy photons with the same polarization as the first?

Comment: So, the inverse of second-harmonic generation? Yes, you can.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to split a photon into two according to the laws of energy and momentum conservation. You can achieve this using non-linear crystals. This is called [parametric downconversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion). Also the polarizations and phases are correlated. This is, however, not a [coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(physics)#Coherence_and_correlation) with the original photon. Coherence requires the same frequency of the photons.

Comment: In that case, the new photons will create an interference pattern through a double slit, since they are in phase and with the same polarization?